# Bat file for Mount/Dismount and delete ISO file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, mount, iso

I'm trying to make a batch-file, which will dismount an ISO file, then delete it. After this it will use the 'cdbxpcmd' command in order to create a new ISO image with the previous same name, and mount it.

For this reason, I've created the following bat script.

```sh
@echo off
powershell -Command "& {dismount-diskimage -Imagepath "C:\juliard\dance.iso}"
del C:\juliard\dance.iso
cd /d "C:\program files\cdburnerxp"
cdbxpcmd.exe --burn-data -folder:D:\ -iso:C:\juliard\dance.iso -format:iso
powershell -Command "& {mount-diskimage -Imagepath "C:\juliard\dance.iso}"
```

Sadly, it keeps on getting stuck on the creation of the ISO step. It seems that it takes ages and after this and you need to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> in order to continue.

1. Can you point me to the wrong commands or if I need to add/remove anything?
2. Do you know any other way, of mounting/dismounting an ISO without calling the PowerShell?

Comment: Seems like a cdburnerxp issue and not a bat or powershell issue

Comment: Your question body says you're using the `cdburnerxp` command, but your code is apparently using a `cdbxpcmd.exe` command. Please clarify by using the [edit] facility and updating whichever accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your replies! I corrected and updated. According to the official site: 

The main application cdbxpp.exe does only have one command line argument: You can only specify a file name of a CDBurnerXP compilation file to open it automatically.

However, the command line version of CDBurnerXP called cdbxpcmd.exe, located in the same program folder as the CDBurnerXP main application, has more useful options.
https://cdburnerxp.se/help/appendices/commandlinearguments